# FungibleAsset implementation in Java won't compile (Corda 4.4)

Tags: java, corda

I'm trying to implement a simple State of type FungibleAsset, even though it seems not that delicate, it gives a compilation error.

> error: TestState is not abstract and does not override abstract method
>   getAmount() in FungibleState public class TestState implements
>   FungibleAsset {
>
> error: getAmount() in TestState cannot implement getAmount() in
>   FungibleState public Amount> getAmount() {
>
> return type Amount> is not compatible with
>   Amount> where T is a type-variable: T
>   extends Object declared in interface FungibleState

```
public class TestState implements FungibleAsset<Currency> {

    Amount<Issued<Currency>> amount;
    AbstractParty owner;

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Amount<Issued<Currency>> getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Collection<PublicKey> getExitKeys() {
        return Arrays.asList(owner.getOwningKey());
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public FungibleAsset<Currency> withNewOwnerAndAmount(@NotNull Amount<Issued<Currency>> newAmount, @NotNull AbstractParty newOwner) {
        return null;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public AbstractParty getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public CommandAndState withNewOwner(@NotNull AbstractParty newOwner) {
        return null;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<AbstractParty> getParticipants() {
        return Arrays.asList(owner);
    }
}
```

While implementing FungibleState works, I don't get what's exactly wrong, I do override required methods.

Answer (score 0):

- `FungibleAsset` interface already has a member called `amount`; no need to introduce your own.
- The correct code would look like this:

```java
import net.corda.core.contracts.Amount;
import net.corda.core.contracts.CommandAndState;
import net.corda.core.contracts.FungibleAsset;
import net.corda.core.contracts.Issued;
import net.corda.core.identity.AbstractParty;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.List;

public class TestState implements FungibleAsset<Currency> {
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Amount<Issued<Currency>> getAmount() {
        return null;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Collection<PublicKey> getExitKeys() {
        return null;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public FungibleAsset<Currency> withNewOwnerAndAmount(
                                       @NotNull Amount<Issued<Currency>> newAmount, 
                                       @NotNull AbstractParty newOwner) {
        return null;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public AbstractParty getOwner() {
        return null;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public CommandAndState withNewOwner(@NotNull AbstractParty newOwner) {
        return null;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<AbstractParty> getParticipants() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I pasted the exact same code, but same error, did it work on your machine?
I guess there's something odd, true `FungibleState` has member `amount: Amount<T>`, `FungibleAsset` overrides that with `amount: Amount<Issued<T>>`. The error message says I'm not overriding `getAmount()` in `FungibleState` !

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. I created a new class and when I typed `implements FungibleAsset<Currency>`; Intellij showed a popup suggesting to implement the interface methods. When I clicked yes, it generated all the functions for me and the class compiled successfully. I suggest that you start from scratch, create a new class and see how it goes.

Comment: Cloned the java template and did just that, a bare minimum class with overrides generated by Intellij but same error message. Did the same thing but with a Kotlin class and it works.
Anyway I will try to make things work with a Kotlin state or find another way around.

Comment: I updated my answer with `import` statements; maybe that would help.

Comment: Exact same imports but nothing, this is weirding me out I even restarted.

Comment: I have the same issue. I think a clarification for @AdelRustum is that the error only shows up when you Build the project. IntelliJ doesn't highlight any errors in the code while you are writing/editing it.

Comment: @AdelRustum update - it's a bug in corda see [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925386/is-fungibleasset-compatible-with-java-cordapps)