# Is FungibleAsset compatible with Java CorDapps?

Tags: corda

This has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61100103/fungibleasset-implementation-in-java-wont-compile-corda-4-4/61100399#61100399) but I will try to approach the question differently.

A quick review of Corda's code:

```
interface FungibleState<T : Any> : ContractState {
    val amount: Amount<T>
}
```

FungibleAsset then extends FungibleState:

```
interface FungibleAsset<T : Any> : FungibleState<Issued<T>>, OwnableState {
    override val amount: Amount<Issued<T>>
    @get:SerializableCalculatedProperty
    val exitKeys: Collection<PublicKey>
    fun withNewOwnerAndAmount(newAmount: Amount<Issued<T>>, newOwner: AbstractParty): FungibleAsset<T>
}
```

If I use FungibleAsset in a Java CorDapp:

```
public class MyFungibleAsset implements FungibleAsset<Currency> {
        
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Amount<Issued<Currency>> getAmount() {
        return null;
    }
...}
```

it will raise 2 errors when I build the project (IntelliJ won't highlight any error during editing):

```
error: MyFungibleAsset is not abstract and does not override abstract method getAmount() in FungibleState

error: getAmount() in MyFungibleAsset cannot implement getAmount() in FungibleState
    public Amount<Issued<Currency>> getAmount() {
                                    ^
  return type Amount<Issued<Currency>> is not compatible with Amount<Issued<? extends Currency>>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface FungibleState
```

I assume this has something to do with FungibleState's getAmount returning `Amount<T>` whereas FungibleAsset's getAmount returns `Amount<Issued<T>>` ?  I don't get an error in kotlin.

Comment: Hey there, just wanted to post that I'm looking into this for you and we're digging into it on the r3 side.

Comment: Hey @tywin lannister, unfortunately it looks like this is a bug in corda, I've reported it internally and this question can hopefully get solved after the bug is fixed. 

Thanks!

Comment: @davidawad that's a relief.  Was worried I was making a noob error.    Will wait for the update.  Thanks for the help and quick response

Comment: anytime! If you're on slack.corda.net you can feel free to hit me up for progress on this or any other questions on Corda. 

Thanks!